# Having an IP address configured on a port, will it participate in Spanning tree protocol instance?

Tags: networking, stp

Having an IP address configured on a port, will it participate in Spanning tree protocol instance?

Answer (score 2):

The spanning tree protocol is a data link layer protocol. It does not understand IP addresses. It can only understand MAC addresses. You can look at [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree_protocol) for a description.